# C++ non-function typedef with parentheses

Tags: c++, function, typedef

How come I can always add a pair of parentheses to a typedef and what does it mean?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main() {
    typedef int td;
    std::cout << typeid(td).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(td()).name() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
i
FivE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`td()` can be one of two things according to the grammar:

- It can be a *type-id*, naming the type "function taking no parameter and returning `td`"
- It can be an *expression*, meaning a value-initialized `td`.

The `typeid` operator can be used with both a *type-id* and an *expression*. This ambiguity is resolved by the standard in favor of it being a *type-id* (§8.2 [dcl.ambig.res]/p2):

> The ambiguity arising from the similarity between a function-style
>   cast and a *type-id* can occur in different contexts. The ambiguity
>   appears as a choice between a function-style cast expression and a
>   declaration of a type. The resolution is that any construct that could
>   possibly be a *type-id* in its syntactic context shall be considered a
>   *type-id*.

In contexts where a *type-id* is not allowed, `td()` would be a value-initialized `td` object. For instance:

```
void foo(int i = int());
```

is equivalent to

```
void foo(int i = 0);
```

Comment: so in the above... is it the return value of td() or td(), seen as a "function object" that has type FivE? If the former, it seems odd that it's not the exact same value as td yields (i)

Comment: @fast-reflexes in `typeid(td())`, `td()` is taken as a type. It's as if you declared `int foo();` and then did `typeid(foo)`.

Comment: just for the clarity of things... Some functions are overloaded with parameters indicating what type they're used for (for example alg function at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags) and I assume we can't supply a type to a function (as a parameter) whereby we instead (in that example) use () after the type, instead of just supplying the type so that the struct, in this case, will be default-constructed and the parameter will actually be an object of that kind, instead of just a general type (which doesn't work) that correct?

Comment: @fast-reflexes right. You can't pass a type as a function argument, so the `()` is taken as constructing an object.

Answer (score 4):

`td()` is `int()`: a function returning `int` taking no parameter.

Comment: Worth noting that there's actually an ambiguity here that the standard resolves in favor of `int()` being a type rather than a value-initialized `int`.

Comment: @T.C. So the return value is a type and not a default-constructed int? Or does this depend on if it's an rvalue or an lvalue? In templates I see T() sometimes and then it seems to be possible to initialize empty slots in a vector with it...